# Города Керчь или города Керчи? Склоняется?

Tags: склонение

Города Керчь или города Керчи? Склоняется ли название?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Правильно: города Керчи.**

ОФИЦИАЛЬНЫЙ САЙТ АДМИНИСТРАЦИИ ГОРОДА КЕРЧИ
[http://керчь-город.рф/?detail=328&r=0&page=239](http://%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4.%D1%80%D1%84/?detail=328&r=0&page=239)

Розенталь: [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#з_07](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm#%D0%B7_07)

Названия городов, выраженные склоняемым существительным, как правило, **согласуются** в падеже с определяемым словом, например: **в городе Москве.**

Согласование **отсутствует в частных случаях**, например:

малоизвестные населенные пункты (сохранение точности названия): в местечке Ельск,

в городе Иваново, из города Пушкино (названия на ОВО/ИНО), нужно различать города Пушкин и Пушкино.